# Distribution function with indicator

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

The probability for the event $\overline{B}$ is $\frac{3}{4}$ and for $B=\frac{1}{4}$.  Find the distribution function of its indicator $I_{\overline{B}}$ and plot the graph.
Indicator of event $B$ is the function $f_{B}(w)=1$, if $w \in B$ and $I_{B} = 0$ , if $w \in \overline{B}$. So I need to calculate $F_{I_{\overline{B}}}(x)$. I haven't seen such a problem anywhere so if someone can suggest how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just identify the event $I_{\overline {B}} \leq x$ for various values of $x$.
 $P(I_{\overline {B}} \leq x)=1$ of $x \geq 1$, $0$ if $x <0$ and it is $P(B)=\frac 1  4$ if $0\leq x <1$.